# Fill the rest of the group with the same value as row 1

Tags: sql, group-by, ranking

I have a database filled with customers and their visited stores. Some of them have done a purchase whereby the receipt number is also listed. I would like to label their 'first buy store' (where the ranking receipt is 1) and fill this for the rest of the customers' rows.

I have already added the 'first buy store' for rows that contain '1' in the column `receipt_rank`.

```
SELECT store, 
       customer, 
       receipt_rank, 
       case 
        when receipt_rank like '1' then store when receipt_rank > 1 then ??? else NULL 
       end as first_buy_store
FROM table
```

But I want to have the first buy store also filled in when the other receipt ranks are filled. This needs to be done/grouped per customer.

What I have now:

| Store | Customer | Receipt_rank (for this customer) | First buy store |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 |  |  |
| B | 1 | 1 | B |
| C | 1 | 2 |  |
| B | 2 |  |  |
| B | 2 | 1 | B |
| C | 3 | 1 | C |
| A | 3 |  |  |
| A | 3 | 2 |  |

What I would like to have:

| Store | Customer | Receipt_rank (for this customer) | First buy store |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 |  |  |
| B | 1 | 1 | B |
| C | 1 | 2 | B |
| B | 2 |  |  |
| B | 2 | 1 | **B** |
| C | 3 | 1 | C |
| A | 3 |  |  |
| A | 3 | 2 | **C** |

Comment: `first_value()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the conditional max window function as the following:

```
select
  store, 
  customer, 
  receipt_rank,
  case 
   when Receipt_rank is not null 
     then max(case when Receipt_rank = 1 then store end) over (partition by customer) 
   else null
  end as First_buy_store
from table_name
```

*Supposing that empty `Receipt_rank` values are nulls*.

[See a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ngFWwese)

Answer (score 0):

This will retrieve the related store for every customer when `receipt_rank = 1`:

```
  select customer, max(store) as store
  from mytable 
  where receipt_rank = 1
  group by customer
```

Then use `left join` to get the expected data :

```
select t.store, t.customer, t.receipt_rank, s.store as 'First buy store'
from mytable t
left join (
  select customer, max(store) as store
  from mytable 
  where receipt_rank = 1
  group by customer
) as s on s.customer = t.customer and receipt_rank >=1
```